# Can I safely point to the data of a reassigned boost::optional?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

Given the following code sample:

```
boost::optional< int > opt;
opt = 12;
int* p( &*opt );
opt = 24;
assert( p == &*opt );
```

Is there any guarantee that the assert will always be valid?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: I did not find the answer in the documentation but maybe I missed it.

Comment: Side note: As long as the pointer is in use the optional must not change it's internal state (optional = boost::none would be fatal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it's a guarantee. The `T` of a `boost::optional<T>` is a logically a private member of the optional.

the code above is logically equivalent to:

```
bool opt_constructed = false;
int opt_i; // not constructed

new int (&opt_i)(12); opt_constructed = true; // in-place constructed

int*p = &opt_i;

opt_i = 24;

assert(p == &opt_i);

// destuctor
if (opt_constructed) {
  // call opt_i's destructor if it has one
}
```

Comment: `*opt` returns a reference to the internal member or throws an exception if it has not been constructed. `opt=24` assigns to the already-constructed member.

Comment: ignore me.  wasn't thinking.

Comment: Can you point the part of the documentation which would back your answer up?

Comment: See the narrative on semantics. Note that an optional is semantically equivalent to T, plus being able to be uninitialised. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/design_overview/the_semantics.html